# Why does JBoss have startup timeout?

Tags: java, jboss

Sometimes I have "Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability." error during JBoss startup, after which JBoss just stops. The solutions I found for this "issue" is just increasing the timeout in the JBoss configuration.

The question is: what is the reason of having such timeout anyway? What problem is solved by it? I believe it is better to have running JBoss (which probably takes some time to start) instead of having stopped JBoss and the error in the logs.

Comment: What's the purpose of any timeout? It prevents the process from hanging indefinitely so that resources can be freed up, and the operation can potentially be reattempted.

Comment: Completely agree with why timeouts are needed. Cannot imagine a database (or an HTTP) client which does not support them. Probably such client would need to be restarted very often to free up resources. But could you give a practical example when it was useful to have timeout for the server startup? Correct me if I am wrong, but, for example, Tomcat does not have such "feature" and it is still OK to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the obvious self control reasons, it is also usefull in HA scenarios, when group of server needs to reach quorum and synchronize state among them.  A stuck server process would cause instability in the group. You should also consider, that sever startup and deployment is often part of a bigger process, e.g. CI build, where you should explicitly state, how long should you block the executor in that step until you decide something is  wrong and free up resources. Furthermore a deployment that takes longer that usual may indicate a problem in your application, e.g. if you put too much logic into bean initialization, or try to acquire external resources like sockets or connections, or an issue with the host OS performance. On the other side, the default value of 300s is just a reasonable default that fits most people, and there is nothing wrong about extending the value to fit your needs.